# Control the iteration range of the generator?

Tags: python

Is there a way that I can control the iteration range of the python generator object?

example: say that a generator consists of 2000 items,  I want one loop to iterate from 1 to 100, and another from 101 to 200, so on.

a simple  `for item in generator` loop will just deplete the generator

Comment: First thought: `itertools.islice`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`itertools.islice(generator, start, stop, step)` is what you want to use.

For example:

```
def generator():
  n = 1
  while n:
    yield n
    n += 1

items = generator()
for item in itertools.islice(items, 100):
  print ('first', item)
for item in itertools.islice(items, 100):
  print ('second', item)
```

Edit: The above of course only lets you take one hundred each time. If you know your generator is finite I would just make it into a list and then iterate over ranges of it. Then you could have arbitrary and overlapping ranges.

Comment: No, this will take `0`-`99`, then `300`-`399`.

Comment: Have a look at the `take` recipe, the first in [`itertools` Recipes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes)